# Why is my question closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Two apache servers on same machine with same port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62740107/two-apache-servers-on-same-machine-with-same-port)

Why is this even closed?

Comment: I suggest reading this FAQ on Meta Stack Exchange: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/194720)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is not a programming question. Neither running nor configuring an Apache server is related to programming.

See: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Note that the close reason in the big blue box tells you this already.

Comment: Read this:

software tools commonly used by programmers

Comment: @JamesB.Reese an e-mail program is also commonly used by programmers, yet not all questions about e-mail programs are on-topic.

Comment: Apache has nothing whatsoever to do with programming. The Help Center's wording is intended to allow questions about development environments, editors, etc., which are commonly used by programmers. Setting up web servers is the job of a system/network administrator. You can get help for that on [SF].

Comment: And then ppl wonder why we are wont about answering or explaining why stuff is moderated. You get a diamond mod taking the time to explain, and get a snarky one liner. But 'old timers are evil'

Comment: I know, isn't that weird, @Patrice? It's usually the diamond mod with the snarky one-liner!

Comment: But this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20147305/apache-virtual-host-is-not-working-right isn't closed

Comment: @James On a site as large as Stack Overflow, some questions are bound to slip through the cracks. I've closed that one now. Please do raise a flag if you find any other off-topic questions. We rely on users to help moderate this site. (To answer your *actual* question: the fact that there exist other off-topic questions does not justify your asking one.)